# How to not duplicate the same base64 image in img and a tags (to display in lightbox for example)

Tags: html, css, base64

I'm building a standalone HTML page and I'm using base64 images inside my document. I want to be able to click on these pictures to enlarge them in lightbox. I don't get the point on how to avoid to duplicate the base64 image in the `<a>` tag to achieve that.
I read about the CSS solution but I don't understand how to pass the base64 to the  tag and to the `<a>`tag.

```html
<a href="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("zoom").innerHTML = this.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("zoom").style.display = "block"
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer
}

#zoom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  display: none;
}

#zoom img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
<div id="zoom"></div>
```

If you need the A tag try this

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "IMG") {
    tgt.parentElement.setAttribute("href",tgt.src);
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try later on my code. I think the second option will make it :)